# Porting a TabViewController based app to Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

I am in the process of porting over an iOS application to the Android platform. I have no experience in this platform and would like to ask for some advice on how best to structure the app. On the iOS end, the app is simply a tabviewcontroller with 3 tabs, each with a list view. The list view is populated with a http request to a server requesting user ids and user information. How can i get these components working in Android?

Comment: For android you can provide tab bar to the top of your activity like: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll need a few components to get it done.

If you know nothing at all about android, before getting started I recommend you learn the basic about layouts, activities and views following this well written guide (Follow the getting started section):

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

**For starters**, you need your UI layout to have tabs, I recommend following this guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

**Second**, you'll need to have a `ListView` component in each tab. Use this simple xml to define a `ListView` component in your layout XML files (this example will take up the entire tab):

```
<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
</ListView>
```

And here's a good guide that explains how to fill the `ListView` with data using an `Adapter`:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

**Third**, you'll need a component that downloads the information from the web server and updates the `Adapter`. This must be on a separate thread, you're not allowed to do network operations on the UI thread in android (to keep the UI available for user actions). You can use `AsyncTask` to do that, following this guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Now, how you parse the data is up to you, but if possible I recommend using JSON and the `JSONObject` class which makes parsing pretty easy.

Good luck and welcome to android!